# format Strings in PHP

Tags: php, string-formatting

I'm tying create a reference generator in PHP, and i need format String.

i tried this code but don't work

```
function refAll($db, $contest, $ano){
$newkey = getlastid($db)+1;
return sprintf("%s%d%1$05d",$contest, $ano, $newkey);}
```

the goal is the output sting formatted like this ABC201500000, where  ABC2015 is fixed and the 00000 is always the value in $newkey but with 5 digits

in my code

> $newkey = 1
>
> $contest = ABC
>
> $ano = 2015

and the output is always ABC201500000

Comment: Your problem is probably in `getlastid()` since that is what generates the value for `$newKey` which is not working.

Comment: the value of $newkey is correct, and if i forced a value sprintf("%s%d%1$05d",$contest, $ano, 1234), give me the same result

Comment: `$05d`? Shouldn't that be `%05d`? $05 means nothing to sprintf

Comment: "the goal is the output sting formatted like this ABC201500000" / "and the output is always ABC201500000". So it's working then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sprintf("%s%d%05d",$contest, $ano, $newkey)
```